# Spring receive login credentials in Post endpoint via @RequestBody and return JSESSIONID

Tags: spring, spring-boot, backend, basic-authentication

I'm creating a Spring JPA application with Spring Security with Basic Authentication for a project.

I want to send login credentials of a user in body, then return JSESSIONID back to user

This is my endpoint that returns a default api endpoint for specific logged in user.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/success" ,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public java.util.Map<String, String> index() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken))
            return Collections.singletonMap("href" ,loginSuccessHandler(((MyUserPrincipal)auth.getPrincipal()).getUser().getId()));
        return Collections.singletonMap("href" ,"/login/error");
    }
```

I have attempted to make custom login with following endpoint (idea is to have a single hardcodable "/success" endpoint after login to give the actual user specific endpoint to frontend).

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Authentication login(@RequestBody ObjectNode JSONObject) {
        String username = JSONObject.get("username").asText();
        String pwd = JSONObject.get("password").asText();

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, pwd));
        boolean isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated(authentication);
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        return authentication;
    }
```

With following SecurityConfig:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
         .csrf().disable()
         .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            // ID ról
            //  admin = 2
            //  student = 1
            //  caretaker = 3
            //  teacher = 4       
                .antMatchers("/api/**").access("hasAnyAuthority('1','2','3','4')")
                .antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
//                  .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll() //tried to use this but it does nothing
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/success", true)
                    .and()
                .logout().and()
                        .httpBasic();
    }
```

Example postman request to send login credentials to Spring:
[Postman post request with credentials in body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvIBF.png)

But said request never enters the "/login" post endpoint.
The only response is whatever I put in the @get "/login" endpoint.

I wish to know how to set up the configuration and the /login endpoints in order for them to authorize user based on credentials from @RequestBody.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public java.util.Map<String, String> getLogin(@RequestBody ObjectNode JSONObject)
    {
        String username = JSONObject.get("username").asText();
        String pwd = JSONObject.get("password").asText();

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, pwd));
        boolean isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated(authentication);
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        return  Collections.singletonMap("href" ,loginSuccessHandler(((MyUserPrincipal)authentication.getPrincipal()).getUser().getId()));
    }
```

get mapping does authorization like here.

Postman result: [Postman request authorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4LjD.png)

By getting the cookie from that via(in Tests tab):

```
var a = pm.cookies.get("JSESSIONID")
pm.globals.set("JSESSIONID", a)
```

Access is possible to secured endpoint: [Working secured endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXDAk.png)